# How to skip replacing first occurrence of a character in each line?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have some files in the format

```
Y15-SUB-B04-P17-BK_M02734_4_000000000-ANNUF_1_1111_24724_4878;size=1;
Y15-SUB-B05-P22-LM_M02734_4_000000000-ANNUF_1_1111_20624_14973;size=1;
Y15-SUB-B05-P22-LM_M02734_4_000000000-ANNUF_1_1103_11326_10379;size=1;
```

I wish to replace every occurrence of the underscore (_) with a colon (:) EXCEPT for the first one. I want an output like this:

```
Y15-SUB-B04-P17-BK_M02734:4:000000000-ANNUF:1:1111:24724:4878;size=1;
Y15-SUB-B05-P22-LM_M02734:4:000000000-ANNUF:1:1111:20624:14973;size=1;
Y15-SUB-B05-P22-LM_M02734:4:000000000-ANNUF:1:1103:11326:10379;size=1;
```

I know I can use `sed -i '' 's/_/:/g' old_file` to replace ALL (or `sed 's/_/:/g' old_file > new_file`), and that I could add numbers to replace only the 2nd, 4th or so occurrence:

```
sed 's/_/:/2' old_file > new_file
```

But how to replace every occurrence on each line BUT the first?

Comment: Maybe a two step process? Replace all underscores with colons, then replace the first colon with an underscore?

Comment: Sure, that would work, only my file is some 14+ gb, and each replacement process takes about 1 hour, so if there were just one parsing step, that would be preferable. Thank you though.

Comment: Ah, so. Good info to have in the question, then. Things like requirements and limitations help us consider the entire situation.

Answer (score 10):

Using GNU `sed` (other versions may behave differently, thanks [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman)):

```
 sed -i'' 's/_/:/2g' file
```

This will change all `_` to `:` skipping the first occurrence on each line.

Comment: This is GNU sed. Other sed implementations act differently when given both `2` and `g` (e.g. the BSD-derived sed on MacOS gives an error)

Comment: ... and [the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) says “If both **g** and *n* are specified, the results are unspecified.”

Answer (score 6):

Using `Posix-sed` constructs only we do like as:

```
$ sed -e '
     y/_/\n/
     s/\n/_/
     y/\n/:/
' inp.file
```

Based on the suggestions by Stephane, some more methods follow here:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(^\G.*?_)?.*?\K_/:/g' inp.file 

$ perl -pe 'my $n; s/_/$n++?":":$&/ge' inp.file 

$ perl -pe 's/_\K(.*)/$1 =~ y|_|:|r/e' inp.file
```

Comment: Or `perl -pe 's/(^\G.*?_)?.*?\K_/:/g'` or `perl -pe 'my $n; s/_/$n++?":":$&/ge'` to do it in one `s///` invocation only.

Comment: This changes the first _ if the line has only one. Also, why the `\G` placeholder? The `^` is sufficient or at least makes the `\G` redundant.

Comment: Yes, it was silly.

Answer (score 5):

Is awk okay? You could use `_` as the field separator, and print out:

```
<field 1>_<field 2>:<field n>:<field n+1>:...
```

Like this:

```
awk -F_ '{ printf("%s_%s", $1, $2); for (x = 3; x <=NF; x++) { printf(":%s", $x); }; printf("\n"); }'
```

If the structure is the same for each line you could hard-code the number of fields to avoid the loop (runs in about 2/3 of the time according to a very rough preliminary trial):

```
awk -F_ '{printf("%s_%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8);}'
```

Comment: Thank you so much - I am unfortunately almost helpless in AWK, so I would have to be spoon-fed the exact command to make it work. if the first file is file1, and the second the output file (file2), then what should I write exactly? Sorry for my ineptitude.

Comment: Add `file1 > file2` to the end of the command, to have it read in file1 and write out to file2. Just like you would with `sed` -- both parse text a line at a time!

Comment: Note the sed commands in the other answers seem to be faster than either of these commands.

Answer (score 5):

With `perl`, to match the character `_` and replace from the first instance on-wards as below.

```
perl -pe '{$n=0}s{_}{++$n > 1 ? ":" : $&;}ge' file
```

The part `s{_}` identifies the `_` within the line and if its the 2<sup>nd</sup> occurrence replace with `:` or replace with the same character(`$&`)

Answer (score 5):

Here is another simple `awk` script, (standard Linux `gawk`), no loops:

```
cat script.awk
match($0,/^[^_]*_/,a){ # match current line to first _ (including) into a[0] variable
   sub(a[0],"");       # remove a[0] from current line
   gsub("_",":");      # replace all _ to : in current line
   print a[0]""$0;     # output a[0] and current line
}
```

run:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

or:

```
awk 'match($0,/^[^_]*_/,a){sub(a[0],"");gsub("_",":");print a[0]""$0;}' input.txt
```

Comment: (1) `sub()` is not a great way to perform surgery on strings, because its first argument is a regular expression.  If the text before the first `_` looks like a regular expression, this is likely to fail.  (2) You know that ``print a[0]""$0`` can be written `print a[0] $0` or `print a[0]$0`, right?  (It’s a matter of style.  I don’t particularly like the ``a[0]""$0`` form, but it’s not wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

A simple sed command will work fine for this:

Command: `sed "s/_/:/2g" filename`

#### Output

```
Y15-SUB-B04-P17-BK_M02734:4:000000000-ANNUF:1:1111:24724:4878;size=1;
Y15-SUB-B05-P22-LM_M02734:4:000000000-ANNUF:1:1111:20624:14973;size=1;
Y15-SUB-B05-P22-LM_M02734:4:000000000-ANNUF:1:1103:11326:10379;size=1;
```

Note: Suppose if you want to replace in the same file, use the below command:

```
sed  -i "s/_/:/2g" filename
```

Comment: This gives me this error message: > sed: 1: "s/:/_/2g": more than one number or 'g' in substitute flags

Answer (score 2):

Given the sample input has no colon characters, a portable sed approach is to convert all underscores to colons, and then convert the first colon back to an underscore.

```
sed 's/_/:/g;s/:/_/' filename
```

@0xSheepdog sort of suggests this in the comments, but failed to point out this could be done with one invocation of `sed`.

Comment: I’m sure *you* know this, but, for the benefit of readers who aren’t as smart as you:  **Warning:** This will fail if any line of input has a colon (``:``) before the first underscore (``_``).